# Start java application in background automatically after boot on embedded linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, embedded, boot

I am using an embedded linux ( Distro: TI SITARA SDK 6.0.0 ) on beaglebone black. I have a java application which runs multiple tcp servers. I need to start this application in background and automatically after every boot. If i login with ssh and run the below code manually (or in bash script) it does work.

```
nohup java -jar application.jar &>log.txt &
```

But if i add this in linux init script and reboot it doesn't.
If i delete last '&' in the line it does work but system resets after 2-3 minutes.

So how can i start my application after every bootup and not causing a reset ?

Comment: put it in a separate executable sh file and run that shell script from init script in a new shell

Comment: can you tell us the distro not the kernel so we can look if this distro has upstart.

Comment: It is a special build from TI SITARA SDK 6.0.0 and starting one script from another doesn't work too. This is what i tried :

echo.sh => 
 `#!/bin/bash
exec &>echoSh.log
echo "I AM ECHO.SH FILE";
`

init.sh =>

`...     ./echo.sh ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with starting my device's watchdog like application in my script. My application works in background but bash scripts stays open until my application stops.